# Missing properties for type (typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue.js, types

In the following:

```
@Mutation
remove_bought_products(productsToBeRemoved: Array<I.Product>) {

    const tmpProductsInVendingMachine: Array<I.Product> = Object.values(this.productsInVendingMachine);
    const reducedProductsInVendingMachine: Array<I.Product> =
        tmpProductsInVendingMachine.reduce((tmpProductsInVendingMachine, { id, ...rest }) => ({ ...tmpProductsInVendingMachine, ...{ [id]: { id, ...rest } } }), {});
    productsToBeRemoved.forEach(({ id }) => reducedProductsInVendingMachine[id].productQty--);
...
```

gives:

```
TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Product[]': length, pop, 
push, concat, and 28 more.
250 |
251 |         const tmpProductsInVendingMachine: Array<I.Product> = Object.values(this.productsInVendingMachine);
> 252 |         const reducedProductsInVendingMachine: Array<I.Product> =
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
253 |             tmpProductsInVendingMachine.reduce((tmpProductsInVendingMachine, { id, ...rest }) => ({ ...tmpProductsInVendingMachine, ...{ [id]: { id, ...rest } } }), {});
254 |         productsToBeRemoved.forEach(({ id }) => reducedProductsInVendingMachine[id].productQty--);
```

What type does the reducer return?

Products are objects that need to be indexed over their id; e.g.

```
[{
    id: 1,
    productName: "coke",
    productPrice: 2, 
    productQty: 20
},
...
]
```

Comment: You're making a very basic error here because you are not familiar with what reduce does to an array. However, you would have already figured that out if you hadn't placed entirely unnecessary type annotations on your local variables. Type inference is your friend, especially when you're figuring out an API.

Comment: You don't create an array with reduce, hence the problem. It returns the last arg, `{}`. If the output is expected to be an array with the same amount of elements as input, consider using `map` instead

Comment: @AluanHaddad in that case it gives "Object possibly undefined" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reducedProductsInVendingMachine` is not an `Array`, its an `Object`.

One possibility is to cast `{}` to the correct type in the initialization parameter of `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```
const reducedProductsInVendingMachine =
    tmpProductsInVendingMachine.reduce(
        (tmpProductsInVendingMachine, { id, ...rest }) =>
            ({ ...tmpProductsInVendingMachine, ...{ [id]: { id, ...rest } } }),
        {} as { [key: I.Product['id']]: I.Product }
    );
```

Notice how the implementation compiles and the `reducedProductsInVendingMachine` variable type is correctly inferred to `{ [key: I.Product['id']]: I.Product }` (with `I.Product['id']` resolved to whatever it is)